# How do I change Namespace in Jena?

Tags: java, xml, jena

I'm copying [tutorial 4 provided by Jena](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/main/jena-core/src-examples/jena/examples/rdf/Tutorial04.java).

I want to add `xmlns:cim="http~~"` to Namespace, but I don't know how.

And I want to change the tag name in the text.
Is there a way to change it to `<cim:Junctionrdf:ID=~~~>` instead of `<rdf:Descriptionrdf:about=~~~>`?

I'm using Java for the first time.
I'll do it myself if you tell me a related function.